# Node.js - Using template literals outside of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-literals

I am reading line by line from a file and assigning each line to a keyed array. My files have each line beginning with their key (e.g name=,text=). 
I am wanting to assign each line to an array without having to manually type out each key.

example:

```
rd.on('line', function(line) {
   line = line.split('=');
   let key = line[0];
   line.shift();
   line = line.join(' ');
   array.name = line;
   // ... Next loop
   line = line.split('=');
   let key = line[0];
   line.shift();
   line = line.join(' ');
   array.text = line;
});
```

Which is NOT what I want

As far as I know template literals are only usable within `'d strings (`console.log(${key})`), though I am hoping there is some way around this that I was unable to find through searching.

The code that I want to work is here:

```
rd.on('line', function(line) {
   line = line.split('=');
   let key = line[0];
   line.shift();
   line = line.join(' ');
   array.${key} = line;
});
```

I am aware that `array.${key}` is invalid syntax and I am hoping someone here has some insight on how I would go about achieving what I am wanting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you use array[key] ? as in a dictionary?

Comment: A "keyed array" sounds an awful lot like "an object with keys as property names whose values are arrays," aka `{ name: [], text: [] }` research the bracket accessor vs the dot accessor

Comment: That is a good point Sanka, I have no idea why that didn't cross my mind in the last hour I've been looking for solutions. That works perfectly fine for assigning each line to a key

Comment: If there are multiple `=` signs, that `.join(' ')` is going to replace the rest of them with spaces. Is that really what you want?

Comment: No it is not Ry, I have that in my To-Do list as fix as it wasn't a priority

Comment: @tehhowch : just used the same name OP has used... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array[key]` where [array is actually a dictionary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to use an Object and not an Array to store the lines based on a specific key.

```
// initiate the Object
let lines = {};

rd.on('line', function(line) {
   line = line.split('=');
   let key = line[0];
   line.shift();
   line = line.join(' ');

   lines[key] = line;
});
```

You can read more about Object basics here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?

```
const data = {}; // I found name `array` confusing
rd.on('line', function(line) {
   const [key, ...rest] = line.split('=');
   data[key] = rest.join(' ');
});
```

One thing though, you are splitting with `=` but joining with  (space character) but maybe this is intentional.

Comment: Yeah the split is to remove the = as I don't want it

Comment: @Sevrene, but if your value in the file is `text=some text=some other text` then in data it will be: `{ text: "some text some other text" }`. Split is removing all the `=` characters in the line.

Comment: Yeah I have that in my to-do list to fix. It just wasn't a priority bug. Will most likely patch that out later tonight

Comment: `.join('=')` should do the trick. In this regard `split` and `join` are reversible.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah I guess you're right, I was stuck in the mindset of `split(' ')` and kept thinking it would fill my spaces with equals when that is not the case